# Is there a good free barcode scanning SDK for non-autofocus cameras on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, barcode, barcode-scanner

I understand there are many questions similar to this on StackOverflow, but this question is very specific so I'm not looking for the typical "Zbar" answer here.

I use the Zbar SDK for barcode scanning (UPC, EAN) on devices with autofocus cameras. But I need a **cheap or free one for non-autofocus devices**, like iPad 2 and iPod touch 4G. My apps are paid or use in-app purchasing.

I have looked at `Scandit`, `RedLaser`, `ShopSavvy`, and `VSBarcodeReader` and they all want high deposit fees (like $1500-$5000 or more) and want to take a ~10% cut. I also saw `Pic2Shop` is free (it uses VSBarcodeReader's scanner) but I don't like how the user has to jump into another app to use the scanning.

Here is what I have found that doesn't fit my needs:

- Red Laser (paid)
- ScandIt (paid)
- VSBarcodeReader (paid)
- ShopSavvy (paid)
- codeREADr (paid)
- Softek (no autofocus)
- zxing (no autofocus)
- Zbar (no autofocus)
- DDH Software (no autofocus)
- QuickMark (no autofocus)
- iCody (bounces users out of the app; users must download app)
- Pic2Shop (bounces users out of the app; users must download app)

This shows that there is an excellent market for an open source project or someone who wants to compete against the big boys at a much cheaper price point.

Anyone have any GOOD alternatives that work and integrate well?

Thanks

Comment: I find the juxtaposition of "My apps are paid or use in-app purchasing" and "I need a cheap or free one" moderately amusing.

Comment: Hi Ethan, I work for Scandit. Have you checked out our community edition? It's a free option if your application is free and consumer facing.

Comment: I have the same question / need. I have an app developed using zbar and it works great on everything above an iPod Touch 4th gen; even the iPad 2 back camera works decently. Despite all my tweaking, I still can't get zbar to work reliably on the iPod Touch. I just implemented the pic2shop external app method but it's clunky and seems to hang sometimes. Brad - for a new developer with a $2 app, the fees these 3rd parties want to charge ($4000+ for a 1 or 2 year license, and some even want 10% on top) isn't practical. We're not being cheap, we're being practical business people.

Comment: Actually, that list shows it's a crowded market with lots of free alternatives and not worth entering. :-) Have you considered enhancing one of the open source offerings (e.g. Zbar) yourself to meet your needs?  That would be honorable.

Comment: Old Pro - I wish I had the skills to do that. Hoping someone else out there already solved the problem. :)

Comment: You can  use this posted answer.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659380/free-barcode-scanner-sdk-for-ios-iphone?rq=1

Comment: Unfortunately feeding a blurry image to ZBar still doesn't allow ZBar to do the scan. Tried that one already.

Comment: -1: I find Brad's remark very accurate here. Also I'm amused that so often people want revenue (paid app), while hoping to use open source solution as much as possible (sometimes not conforming to their licenses - I'm not saying it's the case here!), but not thinking of writing own libraries or contributing to existing ones (giving back to community) or just paying for reliable solutions.

Comment: delirus - Usually I would agree with you but in this case I don't though, sorry. Barcode scanning solutions that are good currently can cost app developers thousands just to get started. For indie developers or one-man shops, that's just no feasible. If I had the skills to do this myself, trust me I would. I'm looking for someone to help.

Comment: I wonder what's so amusing about trying to save money on development costs? Brad ? Delirus ?

Comment: It's not just "saving money on development costs" .... The tools exist. They're out there, specifically addressing this concern. However, the OP wants a free version.

This is just another version of the Photoshop/Gimp problem.

I recommend VSBarcodeReader. Yes it is paid, and you do indeed get what you pay for.

Comment: I've experiment some paid solutions, and basically I was able to notice that sometimes they use the same behavior/workflow/user-experience and the same delegate methods as opensource solutions like ZBar or ZXing. The only noticeable change was the encrusted logo and the requirement for an internet connection to check for licence validity. I am not convinced that all paid solutions can do a better job than free solutions regarding technical issues like the lack of autofocus on hardware. You should stick with ZXing as probably the  best solution you can get without paying or coding it yourself.

Comment: This discussion is a perfect example of why developers don't usually make good businessmen. OF COURSE it's the best option to look for a cheap/free version. There is nothing wrong with this in order to make as much money for your business as possible. You need to take advantage of all available opportunities if you want to make it.

Answer (score 1):

When i saw your question it really shows your hard work.So,much research..I don't know why you didn't check out Grabba..Its free and supports  iPod touch 4G but i don't know whether it supports ipad 2 or not.So,i am sharing the link please check it out.

http://grabba.com/supported-devices/apple

Scandit SDK barcode scanner from Mirasense supports fully iPad 2..

http://www.mirasense.com

But as you already mentioned its not free..

you can also check for PDF417 barcode reader,it is free..

Sorry,this much only i can help you..Let me know if your problem still didn't get solved..

Comment: Sorry but Grabba is a hardware solution and Scandit is paid, as I said above.

Answer (score 0):

The general problem with scanning barcodes on devices with fixed-focus cameras is that for smaller barcodes, it's very hard to get a decent input image for the library from the camera: The image is either not sharp enough, or too small.

For bigger barcodes, I have had good experiences with ZXing on iPad 2, even though it officially does not support fixed-focus cameras. You should give it a try.